# asp.net rich text box control

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, richtextbox

I want a rich text box control using which i can achieve following functionality:

1. Copy from MS word, excel file and paste with formatting being intact.
2. The text is saved in HTML format only. The textbox should return html and not rtf
3. Select word or excel file, the content will show in the text box with formatting intact.

Is there any third party control which will solve my purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at CKEditor http://ckeditor.com/

Comment: That does not have the same formatting when copy pasting from word document

Comment: you can't get what you want with formatting without using an activeX component. I have used many HTML editors and none are perfect with Word pasting. If you will pay, then Telerik Editor is even better with pasting from Word. BUT it's not perfect either